# Wooden piece without a screw hole - is this correct?

Tags: screws, wooden-furniture, hole, table, self-assembly-furniture

This is my first DIY, so please forgive me if my question sounds very naive. I have a whole set of furniture's coming in, so I need to get this bed-side table right!

I am trying to set this up and I have almost everything sorted out, except for one component, you might get an idea from the picture(s) below.

[image]
[image]

Below is the S0 wooden piece:

[image]

Basically I need to fix the S0 piece - but then I do not find any holes on them - unlike all other pieces which had them. Do I need to drill one? If so, what could be the reason that only this piece is left without a hole? How do I go about this?

Comment: Do you have access to a drill?

Comment: Not yet , I would have to buy one if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the material appears to be particle board, one can presume that the screw is pointy enough to create a hole as it is threaded into the wood. You may get away without a drilled hole but expect to see a disruption of the surface on a scale smaller than the volcano in Hawaii.

If the construction permits, place the wood at the brackets, mark the screw location on the wood. Place the wood on a solid surface and begin to drive the screw into the wood. This will allow you to apply sufficient pressure reducing the chance that the screw will strip out the hole being created.

Once you are satisfied that the screw will progress well enough, remove it and place and fasten into position.

You could use a nail and tap it in the same manner but it might be a bit more difficult to remove it. Maybe tap in stages, wiggle and remove, repeat, then drive the screw.

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this. But I am planning to get a drill anyways. So would it be better to use a drill then?

Comment: using a drill will almost certainly improve the results. Pick a bit the diameter of which is slightly smaller than the minor diameter of the screw. You can hold the screw behind the a drill bit and you want to barely see the minor diameter of the screw.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's showing the sides where the screws go and this piece is like fitted to snug up in that space, in front of said screws.. at least from the pieces i built like this that had that sort of front, bottom
.. idk.. whatever you call that face plate board kind of thing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).